# Why are the Skip-extension methods not optimized?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I recently wondered why the `Enumerable`-extension methods like `Skip`, `SkipWhile` or `TakeWhile` are not optimized in order that they use a `for`-loop  instead of enumerating all elements.

Other methods like `ElementAt` first check if the sequence can be casted to `IList<T>`, then they use the indexer to find the element faster. Similar with `First`, `Last`, `Count` etc., they first check if `IEnumerable<T>` can be casted to a collection which supports faster lookups.

Why are the `Skip` methods not omptimized in this way?

Here is what i've got from `ILSpy`(.NET 4), the `SkipIterator` is used for for all skip methods, but similar code is used for `TakeWhile`:

```
// System.Linq.Enumerable
private static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count)
{
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (count > 0 && enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            count--;
        }
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

As you can see it doesn't even try to use a `for`-loop if possible.

Why is the code not similar to this?

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> MySkip<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count)
{
    // check if it's a list or array to use a for-loop
    IList<TSource> listT = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (listT != null)
    {
        if (listT.Count <= count) yield break;
        for(int i = count; i < listT.Count; i++)
            yield return listT[i];
    }

    // no list or array, fallback to .NET method
    foreach (TSource t in source.Skip(count))
        yield return t;
}
```

I have also tested this extension method against the default `Skip`, here is the senseless query that checks how many elements in a list have a follower(always count-1), but it should do the job:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000)
    .Select(i => new { Number = rnd.Next(100) })
    .ToList();

Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();
sw1.Start();

int countAllButLast = randomNumbers
    .TakeWhile((s, i) => randomNumbers.Skip(i).Any())
    .Count();

sw1.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time for default Skip with foreach: {0} Result: {1}", sw1.Elapsed, countAllButLast);

Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
sw2.Start();

countAllButLast = randomNumbers
    .TakeWhile((s, i) => randomNumbers.MySkip(i).Any())
    .Count();

sw2.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time for MySkip with for-loop: {0} Result: {1}", sw2.Elapsed, countAllButLast);
```

The performance difference is tremendous:

```
Time for default Skip with foreach:     00:01:16.5630092 Result: 99999
Time for MySkip with for-loop:          00:00:00.0334746 Result: 99999
```